# Do any visual editors exist for claims-based access control, with several parallel evaluators?

Tags: authentication, access-control

[This MSDN video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Advanced-aspNET-Core-Authorization-with-Barry-Dorrans?ocid=EntriesInArea) at marker 14:20, describes a scenario where an employee can access a building if

1. They are a valid badge carrying FTE
2. They are in possession of a "sticker of shame", temporary badge
3. They are a visitor, and accompanied by a FTE

I'm looking for a visual editor that would handle these types of attributes, similar to the Windows File ACL, but oriented towards claims.

Does any claims based visual editor exist?   I'm primarily looking for how the UX/UI is achieved, without overwhelming the end user.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a product recommendation question, and thus off-topic (and better suited for Software Recommendations SE)?

Comment: I would kindly advise checking what is the intention of limiting "product recommendation requests". Particularly what goes beyond these three words: "describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve." Just because a question contains the word "tool" (or similar) doesn't make it "hey, what's best ..." which StackExchange tries to avoid.

Comment: I'm really only looking for a ux example.  How would the end user interact in theory